# How to get SynthesizedIntrinsicOperatorSymbol instead of SourceUserDefinedOperatorSymbol when doing model.GetDeclaredSymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis

#### I was having trouble with operator resolution as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214209/issues-with-operator-resolution-in-value-types-no-references-added?noredirect=1#comment122362622_69214209) (take a look at this [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kuoyB1)).

In summary, I had code like the following:

```cs
bool a = 3 > 5;
namespace System
{
    public struct Int32
    {
        public static extern bool operator > (int a, int b);
    }
    public struct Boolean { }
}
```

but when I used `GetDeclaredSymbol` on the declaration of the operator it gave me a different `IMethodSymbol` than when I used it in the first line (`bool a = 3 > 5;`).

I was looking for a method like `GetDeclaredSymbol` but that would generate the same symbol that is used in the code as in the declaration.

#### Actual

- `GetDeclaredSymbol` -> `SourceUserDefinedOperatorSymbol`
- `GetSymbolInfo` -> `SynthesizedIntrinsicOperatorSymbol`

#### Wanted (Expected)

- `GetDeclaredSymbol` -> `SynthesizedIntrinsicOperatorSymbol`
- `GetSymbolInfo` -> `SynthesizedIntrinsicOperatorSymbol`

### Basically, I need a way to convert the `SourceUserDefinedOperatorSymbol` into `SynthesizedIntrinsicOperatorSymbol`.

Eg.

```cs
public static IMethodSymbol GetDeclaredSymbol (OperatorDeclarationSyntax ods)
{
    IMethodSymbol opSym = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(ods) ?? throw E;
    if (opSym is SourceUserDefinedOperatorSymbol)
    {
        // convert it to a SynthesizedIntrinsicOperatorSymbol instead
    }
}
```

Comment: But they are different: first one (`usedSymbol`) is of kind `BuitlInOperator`, and `declaredSymbols` is of kind `UserDefinedOperator`. In short - `bool a = 3 > 5;` does not use your operator - it uses built-in operator for ints. So one cannot be "converted" to the other.

Comment: I mean if I define a `UserDefinedOperator`, I would like something that will find the `BuiltInOperator` which matches the declaration.

Comment: Still it's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve. The operators are different. If you had a list of all bulit-in operators then you could in theory go over them one by one and check if any of them matches user defined operator you have (by comparing their signatures).

Comment: @Evk, Yes, I understand the operators are different but I have a `Dictionary<IMethodSymbol, <a method info class>>`. But when I declare `operator > (int, int)`, I want it to add the `BuiltinOperator` to the dictionary not the `UserDefinedOperator` so that when it is used in the code I can match it to the my method info class.

Comment: @Evk, I tried to do the method you are saying but I couldn't figure out how to get a list of the built-in operators. That was the problem I encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have gone with (unless I get a better answer) is to declare my operator declarations like the following:

```cs
public static bool operator > (int a, int b) => a > b;
```

and then to get the symbol for the operator I have the following function:

```cs
public static ISymbol GetDeclaredSymbol(CSharpSyntaxNode? declaration) =>
    declaration is OperatorDeclarationSyntax { ExpressionBody: {} bod } } m &&
    bod.DescendantNodes().OfType<BinaryExpressionSyntax>().SingleOrDefault() is {} bes ?
        model.GetSymbolInfo(bes).Symbol! : model.GetDeclaredSymbol(declaration);
```